# List.js - By date sorting issue

Tags: javascript, sorting, listjs

In my application I am using the List.js for sorting purpose. All the "string" values are working fine. But I do have the "modified date" in the column.

When I click "modified by date" - to sort, this is just considering the date values what is there is the text, ex: 1/4/11.. and sorting accordingly. because of this approach I am getting wrong sort orders.

how can I make instead it should sort by the real value of the number's what the dates are?

Here is my code:

```
new List('mfi-col2', {
       valueNames: ['companyLegalName', 'phazeName', 'contactName', 'number', 'enrollId', 'accountType']
                        });
```

Instead of `"number"` is it possible to send `$(".number").data-number`? So let it use the time stamp that I am getting from server?

Or can anyone suggest an alternative for this plugin?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use this library? It has 25 open issues, is in beta and had its last commit 9 months ago (excluding those two pull requests).

Comment: Just faced same issue. Any solution found? The person who created this lib is active again. He just changed the site interface a few days ago. But not sure how to contact him.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a data-attribute, too:

**js**

```
valueNames: ['date', { name: 'timestamp', attr: 'data-timestamp' }
```

**html**

```
<td class="date timestamp" data-timestamp="1427713871">30/03/2015</td>
```

Now you are able to sort via timestamp without a second or hidden field.

Comment: Good solution. I wasn't aware that list.js can accept data attributes.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but this answer might help new comers.

With each date you display, add a **Timestamps** value in HTML and then compare/sort **Timestamps** values.

One suggestion would be to add the timestamp value as a second hidden HTML `span` in same level where you display your dates. The Timestamp will be used for sorting.

---

**Here's an example of what I used:**

My list is working as a table, and here the `<td>` is the main container.
Then, I used two `<span>` inside a `<td>`.

The first `<span>` called **`c_start` is the actual date being displayed**,
I have the ability to show it with any desired format **(dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yy)** because it's only a display.

As for the sorting, use the second Span `c_start_ts` and have it hidden. In **`c_start_ts` I put the timestamp** value as an whole int number, it's a perfect sort. Even if you later want to apply filtering, it will be easier to handle timestamps values since it can be converted numbers and then compared.

```
<td class="xlarge-head ">
    <span class="c_start">[[FORMATTED-DATE-HERE]]</span>
    <span class="c_start_ts hide">[[PUT-TIMESTAMP-HERE]]</span>
</td>
```

---

Example

```
<td class="xlarge-head ">
    <span class="c_start">01/01/2015</span>
    <span class="c_start_ts hide">1420070400</span>
</td>
```

And then I pass `c_start_ts` to `list.js` to sort, the `TD` in the table will get sorted.

Only recently started to get used to list.js, I see it has potential, but not much docs or support. Hope I helped :)

Comment: FYI, I had to do it this way for it to work with divs:  

    <div class="datevar">
      <span class="hide">1444262400</span>
       Oct. 8, 2015
    </div>

Then I passed 'datevar' as one of the valueNames in the JS code.

Comment: Glad my answered helped, in your method, it seems you placed both the displaying (formatted) date and the timestamp at the same level within the same parent.